# String formatting not displaying correctly

Tags: c#, string, format

I am reading incoming text streams in my C# app, when I look at each string in the debugger and copy and paste its contents into Notepad++ I see that there is clear formatting like so:

```
SEMI MILK                    1      1.19
PERSIL WUL                   1      1.00
BUR JAM DODG                 1      1.25
```

But when I add each string to a List and display on screen like so I see that the formatting is off:

[image]

How can I get the text to diaplay exactly the same as it displays in Notepad++

The display is made up as follows:

```
1. DataGrid _dataGrid;
2. _dataGrid.ItemsSource = TextContent;
3. TextContent = new ObservableCollection<Textline>();
4. TextContent is simply a class with a string Property to store any text for display.
```

Comment: How are you displaying it on screen? Can't you use a grid view of some kind? You haven't specified if this is WinForms/WPF/Console/Other.

Comment: I updated my question

Comment: If you're sticking it into a datagrid surely you just manipulate each column as you see fit?

Comment: I receive each string item as one string and not several so I would not know which word belongs to which column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will probably have to change the font of your DataGrid, try a monospaced font like Courier, Courier New, Lucida Console, Monaco or Consolas. You can also go to your Notepad++ and find the font it is using if you want the same look and feel.

Comment: _dataGrid.FontFamily  = new FontFamily("Courier New");
_dataGrid.FontSize    = 12.0;

Answer (score 0):

You can print to concolse using a  string format and alignment like this

```
 Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0,10}  {1,20} {2, 30}"),
          str1, str2, str3));
```

where `str1`,`str` and `str3` are the fields you want to print

Comment: I am not sure of how many fields I will receive, I simply receive a line of text.